# Django | Guarda las imágenes en otro directorio MEDIA y no en la ruta correcta

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

En vez de guardar las imágenes en el directorio "media\dispositivos" de la raiz, los guarda en "web01\media\dispositivos".
¿Qué sucede?
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo models.py**

```
class ImagenDispositivo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dispositivos/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Imagen dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Imagen de dispositivos'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**settings>local.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

**settings>base.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: Adjunta toda la estructura de directorios de tu proyecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque tienes una carpeta settings/base.py en ves de un archivo settings.py.

La **solución** es cambiar tu BASE_DIR por  esto:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

Tu antiguo BASE_DIR solo subía 2 niveles, pero con este que te he dejado sube 3 niveles.

Comment: Así es. He probado y funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias.